# Does Java Binary Kernel Support work already?

Tags: java

Is this already available in Ubuntu?
https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/java.html

Has someone tried it or is it still just a theory?

Comment: Could someone explain why this got downvoted? After all the kernel documents did not explain what a user needs to do on Ubuntu. After all jar files do not execute just as-is. Not much is missing though.

Comment: Because you could have searched for keywords from the docs you linked to (`binfmt_misc` and java).

Comment: This is anything but clear. Check https://duckduckgo.com/?q=binfmt_misc+java+ubuntu&t=ffab&atb=v230-1&ia=web
It may be that your Google search shows it because of your googling history.

Comment: Didn't say anything about Google. There's search functionality in this site too, with features such as sorting by score, activity, etc.

Answer (score 3):

BINFMT_MISC has been part of linux for a very long time.

Unix has a long history of allowing any file to be treated as an executable, just by putting `#!/path/to/interpreter` as the first line in the file and using `chmod +x` to mark it as executable.

The BINFMT_MISC method is just a slight expansion of that philosophy, where instead of the interpreter name being embedded as text in the first line of the file, you tell the kernel how to recognize a particular binary type and tell it what interpreter to use on that file type.

You can check to see if it is enabled on your system by checking to see if /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc exists:

```
ls -l /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
```

If that exists, there should be a file in it for each supported misc executable type.  On my Ubuntu system, there is a file in there called `jar` that corresponds to java.

Comment: So is it active on Ubuntu?

Comment: Updated answer so you can check for yourself.

Comment: I checked already. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I just took a jar file, marked it as executable and was able to run it by just putting the jar filename into the shell. This BINFMT stuff seems to be installed and active. :-)

```
$ chmod +x some.jar
$ ./some.jar
```

This is great! :-)

Comment: Hmmm. Just having upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 I notice this feature no longer works.

Comment: Possibly you don't have a java interpreter installed....

Comment: I only upgraded - it is not an installation from scratch. Before I had Java 16 as system default, now it is Java 17. But it is not registered for executing jar files.